# Creating a working kubernetes environment using Docker

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I cloned [kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes) repo and set up a working environment using Docker. I started Docker, and then I ran "make quick-release". But it seems to be stuck at [this instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHEZp.png). I am using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want **K**ubernetes **in** **D**ocker, that's what [KinD](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/) is for.